# replace nans with normal distribution of the moving window

Tags: python, numpy, random, nan

I need to replace NaNs of 1D array with local normal distribution in numpy. I select a window, calculate mean and std of that window then use normal distribution to replace NaNs, while the rest of the signal stays the same.

```
import numpy as np

def replace_nan(signal, window = 5):
    """
    calculate moving average and std of signal window without nan    
    replaces nan values with normal distribution (mean, std)    
    """
# add padding in case signal starts/ends with nan
    signal = np.pad(signal, (window, window), 'mean', stat_length = 2*window)    

    for k in range(window,len(signal)-window):        
        mean = np.nanmean(signal[k-window:k+window])  # window average 
        std = np.nanstd(signal[k-window:k+window]) # window std without nan 

        ind = np.where(np.isnan(signal[k-window:k+window]))[0]    
        print (ind)   
        signal[ind]= np.random.normal(mean, std)

    signal = signal[window:len(signal)-window] #remove padding

    return signal

#tester 
signal = np.array([0.71034849, 0.17730998, 0.77577915, 0.38308111, 
0.24278947, np.nan, np.nan, 0.68694097, 0.6684736 , 0.47310845, 0.22210945, 
0.1189111, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.5573841 , 0.57531205, 0.74131346, 
0.29088101, 0.5573841 , 0.57531205, 0.74131346, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 
np.nan, 0.49534304, 0.18370482, 0.06089498, 0.22210945, 0.1189111])        

signal = replace_nan(signal, 5)

print(signal)
```

I replace nans with the normal distribution np.random.normal() with mean and std calculated for the moving window with size 5. Something is wrong when I select those nans of the signal window to replace them. It should be easy, I am just a complete beginner with python.

Comment: You can improve your question by giving a concrete example.

Comment: hmm, I need to think how to do it. I use large signals and plot them to see the concrete examples. But it looks like I cannot upload signal and figures here/ or i can upload and did not find where? Maybe i missed where to include data/figures...

Comment: For instance. `signal = np.array([0.71034849, 0.17730998, 0.77577915, 0.38308111, 0.24278947, np.nan, 0.68694097, 0.6684736 , 0.47310845, 0.22210945, 0.1189111 , np.nan, 0.5573841 , 0.57531205, 0.74131346, 0.29088101, np.nan, 0.49534304, 0.18370482, 0.06089498])`?

Comment: The Body field of your question has a ribbon with several small icons. You can see what function they perform by hovering above them. Inserting a figure helps but is not sufficient. It is best to also include a small data sample, show what your code is doing with it in the figure and then what the desired output is.

Comment: tried to edit, maybe now it is better

Comment: @KRKirov  I scratched my head and re-wrote it all completely, I hope it's better to understand, but it still does not work :(... Maybe you'll be able to spot a mistake/mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested if the numbers work out exactly, but I think this will work:

```
import numpy as np

def replace_nan(signal, window = 5):
    """
    calculate moving average and std of signal window without nan
    replaces nan values with normal distribution (mean, std)
    """

    # add padding in case signal starts/ends with nan
    signal = np.pad(signal, (window, window), 'mean', stat_length = 2*window)

    for k in range(window, len(signal) - window + 1):
        mean = np.nanmean(signal[k-window:k+window])  # window average
        std = np.nanstd(signal[k-window:k+window]) # window std without nan

        if np.isnan(signal[k]):
            signal[k] = np.random.normal(mean, std)

    signal = signal[window:len(signal)-window] #remove padding

    return signal

#tester
signal = np.array(
    [
        0.71034849, 0.17730998, 0.77577915, 0.38308111, 0.24278947, np.nan,
        np.nan, 0.68694097, 0.6684736 , 0.47310845, 0.22210945, 0.1189111,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.5573841 , 0.57531205, 0.74131346,
        0.29088101, 0.5573841 , 0.57531205, 0.74131346, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, 0.49534304, 0.18370482, 0.06089498, 0.22210945,
        0.1189111
    ]
)

print("Before:")
print(signal)

signal = replace_nan(signal, 5)

print("\nAfter:")
print(signal)
```

This gives:

```
Before:
[ 0.71034849  0.17730998  0.77577915  0.38308111  0.24278947         nan
         nan  0.68694097  0.6684736   0.47310845  0.22210945  0.1189111
         nan         nan         nan  0.5573841   0.57531205  0.74131346
  0.29088101  0.5573841   0.57531205  0.74131346         nan         nan
         nan         nan  0.49534304  0.18370482  0.06089498  0.22210945
  0.1189111 ]

After:
[ 0.71034849  0.17730998  0.77577915  0.38308111  0.24278947  0.35960417
  0.508657    0.68694097  0.6684736   0.47310845  0.22210945  0.1189111
  0.50282732  0.34906067  0.31206557  0.5573841   0.57531205  0.74131346
  0.29088101  0.5573841   0.57531205  0.74131346  0.80133879  0.63122315
  0.49236281  0.35630875  0.49534304  0.18370482  0.06089498  0.22210945
  0.1189111 ]
```

Comment: yes, perfect. i knew it should be easy! thank you (if np.isnan(signal[k]):
            signal[k] = np.random.normal(mean, std)) much better.  A bit out of topic: i see my sintax habits are not great, is it ok to add working parts to stackoverplow and ask for syntax improvement advices?

Comment: Np! :) Syntax questions? Not sure that is the best question for StackOverflow. But I can give you some pointers here and now. Typically python programmers follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). And if you use an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), like [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) it will let you know as you type if your syntax is off.

Comment: thank you, looked through pep8, yes, i was doing it wrong.... installed pycharm now. It's better to pick up good habits from the start then to change them later